# SQLAlchemy validation - what is the key parameter?

Tags: python, validation, sqlalchemy

I am writing validation methods on my tables. I'm using the `@validates` decorator and everywhere I see examples of how to use it, there's a `key` parameter but it is not being used in the validation method. So what is it? Do I need to add it as a parameter?
Example:

```
class Person():
  age = Column(Integer)

  @validates('age')
  def validate_age(self, key, age):
    assert age >= 18
    return age
```

So again, all the examples I'm seeing do something similar and they all have a `key` parameter but it's not being used. Can I remove it?

Comment: The key parameter is the Table Primary Key.